# How to pip install from a private artifactory?

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

A private artifactory is available. We pushed a Python lib into it using `Twine`:

```
/python-XYZ/mylib/version/mylib-version.tar.gz
```

However, I do not understand how we can get this library using `pip install`.

I have tried the following (based on [this](https://www.zepl.com/use-your-private-python-libraries-from-artifactory-in-zepl/)):

```
pip install mylib==version --index 'https://myuser:mypassword@XYZ-DOMAIN.fr:443/artifactory/api/pypi/python-XYZ/simple
```

Which gives this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mylib==version (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mylib==version
```

The result is the same with the following endpoints:

```
/artifactory/api/pypi/python-XYZ/mylib/simple
/artifactory/api/pypi/mylib/simple
/artifactory/api/pypi/python-XYZ/simple
```

Given the location of my library, how can I `pip install` it ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `pip install mylib==version --extra-index-url https://myuser:mypassword@XYZ-DOMAIN.fr:443/artifactory/api/pypi/python-XYZ/simple` ?

Comment: pip install --extra-index-url https://myuser:mypassword@XYZ-DOMAIN.fr:443/artifactory/api/pypi/python-XYZ/simple mylib==version

Comment: The web UI in Artifactory shows you exactly how to use a repo when you navigate to it and click the "set me up" link on the upper right.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, here is what it should be in my case.

```
pip install mylib==version --index-url 'https://USERPWD@XYZ-DOMAIN.fr:443/artifactory/api/pypi/python/simple' --trusted-host=XYZ-DOMAIN.fr
```